# How do I make this integration test unit test with mocking?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am new to mocking. I am having an integration test, which I want to change to unit test. I know I have to mock balancePositiveCalculator, since it is cooperating dependency with classUnderTest, but I am not sure how to mock here so I am only testing classUnderTest. Do I have to create mock of balancePositiveCalculator and setup parameters and canned return and then use mock object method to calculate costs.FeesAndInterest? I am using moq.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Calculate_VirtualSaving_PositiveSaving()
{
    var balance = 100M;
    var monthlyRepayment = 20M;
    var currentInterestRate = 18.9M;
    var savingsExpected = 24M;

    var fakeCreditCard = new CreditCardGold { Money = 15 };

    var currentFees = _classUnderTest.Calculate(balance, currentInterestRate, monthlyRepayment, 0M, 1);
    var balancePositiveCalculator = new BalancePositiveCalculator(_classUnderTest);
    var costs = balancePositiveCalculator.Calculate(fakeCreditCard, balance, monthlyRepayment);

    var savingsActual = currentFees.InterestPaid - costs.FeesAndInterest;

    savingsActual.ShouldBeInRange(savingsExpected - 1M, savingsExpected + 1M);
}
```

Edit(I tried this). Is this correct approach:

```
var fakeCalculatorResult = new CalculatorResult
{
    FeesAndInterest = 12
};

var mockBalancePositiveCalculator = new Mock<IBalancePositiveCalculator>();
mockBalancePositiveCalculator
    .Setup(x => x.Calculate(It.IsAny<CreditCardGold>(), It.IsAny<decimal>(), It.IsAny<decimal>()))
    .Returns(fakeCalculatorResult);

// act
var currentCreditCardCost = _classUnderTest.Calculate(balance, currentInterestRate, monthlyRepayment, 0M, 1);
var costs = mockBalancePositiveCalculator .Object.Calculate(It.IsAny<CreditCardGold>(), It.IsAny<decimal>(), It.IsAny<decimal>());

var savingsActual = currentCreditCardCost.InterestPaid - costs.FeesAndInterest;

// assert      
savingsActual.ShouldBeInRange(savingsExpected - 5M, savingsExpected + 5M);
```

Comment: "Do I have to create mock of balancePositiveCalculator and setup parameters and canned return and then use mock object method to calculate costs.FeesAndInterest? I am using moq." Exactly this, I´m not sure on the exact syntax in Moq, it should be something like `balancePositiveCalculator  = Moq.Setup<BalancePositiveCalculator>()` and than call `Calculate` on the mock-object as if it was a normal instance.

Comment: You appear to have your dependencies back to front. It would make sense if you were testing `BalancePositiveCalculator` to then mock out the type of `_classUnderTest`. However in your scenario, just call methods directly on the `_classUnderTest` and remove any code related to `BalancePositiveCalculator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I agree with @Lee Campbell - you have your dependencies back to front.  What you want to do is mock any dependencies in your class and then inject them in.  That's why IOC containers are so popular when it comes to writing unit testable code.  Your implementation of "_classUnderTest" has no dependencies and therefore can be unit tested on it's own.  However "BalancePositiveCalculator" has a dependency on the "_classUnderTest" and that's what you want to mock and inject into "BalancePositiveCalculator".

The test would then look something like the following:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void BalancePositiveCalculator()
    {
        var balance = 100M;
        var monthlyRepayment = 20M;
        var currentInterestRate = 18.9M;
        var savingsExpected = 24M;

        var fakeCreditCard = new CreditCardGold { Money = 15 };

        var classUnderTestMock = new Mock<IClassUnderTest>();
        classUnderTestMock.Setup(
            test =>
                test.Calculate(It.IsAny<decimal>(), 
                    It.IsAny<decimal>(), 
                    It.IsAny<decimal>(), 
                    It.IsAny<decimal>(),
                    It.IsAny<decimal>()))
            .Returns(new ClassUnderTest());

        classUnderTestMock.Setup(test => test.InterestPaid).Returns(balance);

        var balancePositiveCalculator = new BalancePositiveCalculator(classUnderTestMock.Object);
        var costs = balancePositiveCalculator.Calculate(fakeCreditCard, balance, monthlyRepayment);

        var savingsActual = classUnderTestMock.Object.InterestPaid - costs.FeesAndInterest;

        savingsActual.ShouldBeInRange(savingsExpected - 1M, savingsExpected + 1M);

    }
```

Which would also mean that you would obviously have an interface like the following:

```
public interface IClassUnderTest
{
    ClassUnderTest Calculate(decimal balance, 
        decimal currentInterestRate, 
        decimal monthlyRepayment, 
        decimal num1, 
        decimal num2);

    decimal InterestPaid { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all you do with the `BalancePositiveCalculator` is creating an amount which gets subtracted from another amount, you can omit that completely. Effectively, you test `_classUnderTest.Calculate` only, more exactly the `InterestPaid` property of its return value.

I'd prefer to add some `Assert`s for other properties of the return value.

As for the `BalancePositiveCalculator.Calculate` method, add some tests there.